# Excel Forumula - Adding working hours to date and time

Tags: excel-formula

I am currently using a forumla to add working hours to a start date and time:

```
=WORKDAY(A1,INT(B1/8.5)+IF(TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)>TIME(17,30,0),1,0),$D$1:$D$21)+IF(TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)>TIME(17,30,0),TIME(9,0,0)+TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)-TIME(17,30,0),TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0))
```

Cell A1 is the start date, Cell B1 is the amount of hours to add, and column D is bank holidays

So far this works great, however if the start date and time is outside of the 9:00 to 17:30, then it shows the wrong date and time.

Is there any reason why this happens? and what i can do to overcome this issue?

For example:

```
        A               B             C                   D
24/08/2019 10:31:17    16      28/08/2019 09:31       26/08/2019
```

Column C is where the forumla sits and in this example of only adding 9 Hours. Column A's date is logged outside of working hours, on a saturday. The correct date and time should be 28/08/2019 16:30 as it will start counting after bank holiday on the Monday.

Comment: Please share a few lines of sample data showing where went ok, where went wrong, and the expected output.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question i have with an example :)

Comment: Even with added example your assumptions are still unclear. Can you please specify the following: **1)** If the start time is before 9:00 AM, are you going to treat it as starting from 9:00 AM or from the actual time? **2)** If the end time is after 5:30 PM, are you going to count the actual hours worked or simply round it to 8.5 hours, and how about `lunch break/tea break`? **3)** If the finish time is between 9:30 AM and 5:30 PM, are you going to deduct the actual hours worked from the additional hours, and add the remaining to the next workday and presume it starts from 9:00 AM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue myself using two sets of formulas depending if the date and time falls in or out of working time:

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A1,2)<6,HOUR(A1)>9,HOUR(A1)<17.5,COUNTIF(D1:D21,DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))=0),WORKDAY(A1,INT(B1/8.5)+IF(TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)>TIME(17,30,0),1,0),$D$1:$D$21)+IF(TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)>TIME(17,30,0),TIME(9,0,0)+TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)-TIME(17,30,0),TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)),WORKDAY(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0),INT(B1/8.5)+IF(TIME(HOUR(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)),MINUTE(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)),SECOND(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)>TIME(17,30,0),1,0),$D$1:$D$21)+IF(TIME(HOUR(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)),MINUTE(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)),SECOND(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)>TIME(17,30,0),TIME(9,0,0)+TIME(HOUR(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)),MINUTE(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)),SECOND(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)-TIME(17,30,0),TIME(HOUR(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)),MINUTE(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)),SECOND(WORKDAY(A1,1,D1:D21)+TIME(9,0,0)))+TIME(MOD(B1,8.5),MOD(MOD(B1,8.5),1)*60,0)))
```