# How to add work hours to a date with time?

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to add business hours to some date. The issue is when I set the Start Date during Holidays.
For example: I set

```
Column A3 - Start date - 2020-07-09 8:01
Column B3 - Add hours: 2
Column E2 - Start hour: 8:00
Column F2 - End hour: 17:30
Column G2:G - Holiday: 9/7/2020
```

I used this formula:

```
=IF(A3="","",WORKDAY(A3,INT(B3/9.5)+IF(TIME(HOUR(A3),MINUTE(A3),SECOND(A3))+TIME MOD(B3,9.5),MOD(MOD(B3,9.5),1)*60,0)>$F$2,1,0),$G$2:$G)+IF(TIME(HOUR(A3),MINUTE(A3),SECOND(A3))+TIME(MOD(B3,9.5),MOD(MOD(B3,9.5),1)*60,0)>$F$2,$E$2+TIME(HOUR(A3),MINUTE(A3),SECOND(A3))+(TIME(MOD(B3,9.5),MOD(MOD(B3,9.5),1)*60,0)-$F$2,TIME(HOUR(A3),MINUTE(A3),SECOND(A3))+TIME(MOD(B3,9.5),MOD(MOD(B3,9.5),1)*60,0)))
```

And the result was incorrect. It shows me: `2020-7-9 10:01` but it should be `2020-7-10 10:01`.

UPDATE:
There are few cases, which had to be good: 
a)Start 2020-07-09 8:01 ->  Add 1 hour -> result - 2020-07-10 9:01 
b)Start 2020-07-09 7:00 ->  Add 1 hour -> result - 2020-07-10 9:00 
c)Start 2020-07-09 17:31 -> Add 1 hour -> result - 2020-07-10 9:00 
d)Start 2020-07-09 00:00 -> Add 1 hour -> result - 2020-07-10 9:00

And also: 
a)Start 2020-07-10 8:01 ->  Add 1 hour -> result - 2020-07-10 9:01 
a)Start 2020-07-10 20:22 ->  Add 1 hour -> result - 2020-07-13 9:00

Any help?

UPDATE:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq6bs.png

Comment: What is this functiuon? "+TIME MOD(B3,9.5)" never seen TIME MOD(). Are there any functions with spaces in the name?

Comment: TIME - Converts a provided hour, minute, and second into a time and MOD() - Returns the result of the modulo operator, the remainder after a division operation.   And there is not any space in the name.

Comment: So you actually meant to put this"+TIME(MOD(B3,9.5)) ? perhaps you missed a couple of characters?

Comment: I have a brackets, there is a mistake above... I didn't seen that. But still it isn't an issue ;(

Comment: The formula you have provided gives a formula parse error, WORKDAY should have 3 values not 4. Can you fix this?

Comment: I don't have any error. You have to add a bracket befor first TIME"("MOD()

Comment: =IF(A3="","", WORKDAY(A3,INT(B3/9.5)+IF(TIME(HOUR(A3),MINUTE(A3),SECOND(A3))+TIME(MOD(B3,9.5),MOD(MOD(B3,9.5),1)*60,0)>
$F$2,1,0),$G$2:$G)+IF(TIME(HOUR(A3),MINUTE(A3),SECOND(A3))+TIME(MOD(B3,9.5),MOD(MOD(B3,9.5),1)*60,0)>$F$2,$E$2
+TIME(HOUR(A3),MINUTE(A3),SECOND(A3))+TIME(MOD(B3,9.5),MOD(MOD(B3,9.5),1)*60,0)-$F$2,TIME(HOUR(A3),MINUTE(A3),SECOND(A3))
+TIME(MOD(B3,9.5),MOD(MOD(B3,9.5),1)*60,0)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as a new answer.  It is very specific to the logic requirements of the original question.
Sample worksgeet is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kmXE6QlqRLFNS9rKNwiqTX-blgJKjj8w0SayJVeQdZo/edit?usp=sharing

Main formula is as follows:

```
=if(or(
    weekday(A6,2)>5,
    iferror(match(INT(A6),$H$1:$H12,0),FALSE)),
      workday(A6,
              INT(1 + int(B6/9.5) ),
              Sheet2New!Holidays)
        + (8 + mod(B6,9.5))/24 ,
      workday(A6,
              INT(0 + int(B6/9.5) + if((if(D6/24<$B$2,8,D6) + mod(B6,9.5))-$D$3>0,1,0)),
              Sheet2New!Holidays)

        + if(round(D6/24,4)<=$B$2,
            8+mod(B6,9.5),
            if(round((D6 + mod(B6,9.5))/24,4)>=$B$3,
              if(round(D6/24,4)>=$B$3, 
                8 + mod(B6,9.5),
                8 + mod(B6,9.5)-($C$3*24-D6)),
            D6 + mod(B6,9.5)))  /24)
```

It could use a lot of cleaning up, but will leave that until after seeing if it works for you.

It basically uses WORKDAYS to cacluate a future date, based on a starting date/time, and an added number of hours.  The first part of the formula focuses on getting the new date right, and the second part focuses on getting the new start time.

The logic rules include:

Working hours are limited to 08:00 to 17:30, or 9.5 hours per day.

If start date is a holiday, jump to the next working day at 08:00, plus offset by the amount of hours specified, keeping a max of 9.5 hours per day, and only working days.

If start time is before 08:00, jump ahead to 08:00, plus hours.

If start time is after  17:30, jump ahead to 08:00 the next working day, plus hours.

If hours added would result in going past 17:30, add remaining hours to 08:00 the next working day.

Let me know if it tests out okay.

UPDATE: Revised formula to also check if starting on a weekend.  If so, treat the same as if starting on a holiday.

Comment: Almost done! But I tried to set a start date 2020-07-12 10:00, plus 1 hour, and the result is 2020-07-12 11:00. It should be 2020-07-13 9:00. So issue is also when start date is a date during weekend.  Could you also correct that?

Comment: Fixed.  Just added a simple day of the week check, and treat the date the same as if starting on a holiday.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You are awesome! It looks like everything working well! I apologize for the lack of precision at the beginning.  Thanks for your time :)

Comment: As the person asking the original question, you can flag any answer here as having helped you, or met your objective, so others searching on a similar issue can benefit from useful answers.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Could you also make an array formula from this formula? or I need to open new request? Because when I change it to array it does not work :/

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the first half of your equation deals only with days/dates, and the second half with hours.

So this portion of your equation:

```
WORKDAY(A3,INT(B3/9.5)+IF(TIME(HOUR(A3),MINUTE(A3),SECOND(A3))+TIME(MOD(B3,9.5),MOD(MOD(B3,9.5),1)*60,0)> $F$2,1,0),$G$2:$G)
```

returns a date of "2020-07-09" (format it as a datetime and you'll see "2020-07-09 00:00"), and the second half of your equation adds 10+ hours to it, giving a datetime value of "2020-07-09 10:01".

I assume you want to add 10 working hours to the start of the working day, 8:00AM, which would carry over in to the next working day.

UPDATE:  Here is a sample sheet where adding hours to a date can be tested.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ceCLUhjAm_4nj18K7GhXq6hz_z42PxyQC3PDpyRID6I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Exactly, and there is an issue because i don't know how to do it. Could you write to me a correct formula? I want to add even 1hour, but when I set a start date the same as date in Holiday it should me show the next working day + this hour.

Comment: I see one main issue.  If you set your starting date to be on a holiday, or on a weekend, WORKDAY doesn't seem to skip over it, so you might need a lot of logic to check for and address those possibilities.  Otherwise, this formula seems to do some of the math right:
```=WORKDAY(A3,B3/24 + TIMEVALUE(A3)/24,G2:G) + TIMEVALUE(A3)```
Since WORKDAY ignores hours, we add the initial starttime, plus the hours worked, both divided by 24, to get the number of days going forward.  Then we add back on the initial starttime to get a final date and time.

Comment: If we want to factor in only allowing 8 working hours per day, so that adding 10 hours equals adding 1.25 days, then that would require some extra logic.  And is the start of your day 8:00AM or something else?  Let us know if that is what you need.

Comment: Still it doesnt work. There are few cases for start date and the answer should be like that:  a)Start 2020-07-09 8:01 -> adding hours-1 -> result - 2020-07-10 9:01    b)Start 2020-07-09 7:00 -> adding hours - 1 -> Result - 2020-07-10 9:00   c)Start 2020-07-09 17:31 -> adding 1hour -> result - 2020-07-10 9:00    d)Start 2020-07-09 00:00 -> Adding 1 hour -> Result 2020-07-10 9:00           Holiday is stil at 2020-07-09. And work time is between 8:00 - 17:30.

Comment: I found almost good resolution but not really... There is a mistake ( i wrote a question there). 
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711191/excel-forumula-adding-working-hours-to-date-and-time/62832977#62832977

Comment: @Adam, when you say there is a mistake in that other question, because the formula doesn't give the answer you expect, can you please provide that in a sample sheet so that we can see the incorrect answer, and the answer that you expect?  That makes it easier, rather than starting over in another question.

Comment: I've added a sample sheet in my above answer, and don't see any error when adding hours, or fraction of an hour, to a datetime.

Comment: I added a link in main question

Comment: I added second sheet, please look on it. I used other formula. But it still doesn't work correctly.   In your sheet, I change the hour and there is mistake

Comment: Adam, all of your examples show adding just a few hours.  Is it possible that you could be adding a larger number of hours - like 20 to 100?  It might change the logic.  And for holiday dates, I assume that should be a longer list, like all of the typical stat holidays, plus maybe some exceptional ones you add to the list?

Comment: Also, could you have different start times and end times for different days, or always 8AM to 5:30PM?  If different, I think any formula would be massively complex...

Comment: One more question.  If your starting datetime is 8:30 on a holiday, and you add 1 hour, do you want the new datetime to be 9:00 on the next working day, or 9:30?

Comment: About holidays, yes there will be more non working days, for example christmas days (25th, 26th December and others). Yes, I will be add more hours, but not bigger then 100 (it depends, but I will add connection with the cell in sheet). The work hours will be always 8AM to 5:30 PM. And last answer: The new datatime should be 9:00, when I add for example 10hours, it should be the 2 days after holiday and datatime should be 8:30 then.

Comment: You have one example I'm unclear on: Start datetime = 2020-07-10 05:00 (a Friday)  plus 1 hour, and you show the desired result is:  2020-07-13 08:30 (Monday).  Is this correct?  Or should the result be 2020-07-10 09:00?  Adding 1 hour to the earliest start time of 8AM?

Comment: if you were you thinking of an original starttime of 2020-07-10 17:00,  Friday at 5PM, and you add one hour, do you want the result Monday at 9AM, or at 8:30AM?

Comment: This is not correct, there it should show 2020-07-10 9:00. And about second question: It should show Monday at 8:30 AM.